# multiple selection in the where clause

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

I need to do multiple selection in the where clause

```
select * 
  from BATS
  where REASON in
case when :P12_REASON = 'Rejects' then ('online', 'offline') else '' end
and
case when :P12_REASON = 'accepted' then ('online', 'offline', 'written') else '' end
and
goings on.....
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to rewrite the clause using `AND` logic:

```
SELECT *
FROM BATS
WHERE (:P12_REASON = 'Rejects' AND REASON IN ('online', 'offline') OR
       :P12_REASON = 'accepted' AND REASON IN ('online', 'offline', 'written'))
  AND -- goings on...
```

Note the parentheses around this logic are necessary to avoid improper grouping with the logic following the `AND`.

Answer (score 1):

It's generally better to use `AND`/`OR` instead of `case` expressions in the `WHERE` clause.

```
select * 
from BATS
where :P12_REASON = 'Rejects' AND REASON IN ('online', 'offline')
   or :P12_REASON = 'accepted' AND REASON IN ('online', 'offline', 'written')
   ...
```